# How to Secure the lua scripts inside Nodemcu

Tags: lua, iot, nodemcu, lua-scripting-library

I am writing a script having user personal information like "User Id", "Password", "Server detail", Bla bla bla. And I want to secure these all personal data.

And you know, Script inside Nodemcu is not secure at all. Anybody can download the script and make a cop of my project.
So, I want to encrypt the script which is uploaded in the Nodemcu so that some other can not decrypt or read my script.

Is it possible in NodeMCU?
I am using NodeMCU V3(Written at the back side of nodemcu)
Initial Details :

```
NodeMCU custom build by frightanic.com
    branch: 1.5.4.1-final
    commit: b9436bdfa452c098d5cb42a352ca124c80b91b25
    SSL: false
    modules: file,gpio,mqtt,net,node,rtctime,tmr,uart,wifi
 build created on 2019-09-21 17:56
 powered by Lua 5.1.4 on SDK 1.5.4.1(39cb9a32)
lua: cannot open init.lua
```

Comment: A) such information does not belong into the script B) if somehow has physical access to the device it's game-over anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to achieve high security level but not 100%. NodeMCU stores data in external flash which is not protected from reading, even encrypted.

You need at least a firmware with standard crypto and TLS modules for basic encryption. Without TLS encryption (as module for net communication) you are vulnerable event without touching your device.

Better, is to use modified firmware with custom encryption/decryption functionality using internal unique chip id's as part of key, making it harder to break.

Some interesting ideas: https://bbs.espressif.com/viewtopic.php?t=936

To protect your scripts, compile in binary form without storing original scripts: https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/compiling/

Edit:

In module [crypto](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/blob/master/app/modules/crypto.c) you can add a modified version of `crypto_encdec()` as `encryptintern`/`decryptintern` with predefined/calculated key and iv.

To get device specific id for key calculation you can use MAC address with `wifi_get_macaddr()` and flash id with `spi_flash_get_id()` as suggested: https://bbs.espressif.com/viewtopic.php?t=1303

To encrypt/decrypt compiled scripts you can modify `luaL_loadfile` (`require` uses it too) to decrypt files, and `luac.c` for encryption on your host.

Comment: "Better, is to use modified firmware with custom encryption/decryption functionality using internal unique chip id's as part of key, making it harder to break."

Can you provide a link of proper Guidance on this?

Answer (score 0):

Note that nothing will help against an even halfway determined person. It's trivial to dump the contents of flash, find keys, and decrypt everything. Without hardware support (there are cheap crypto chips out there), it is impossible to secure these devices.

Depending on your situation, there are alternatives; for example, for my home usage I'm planning to set up a separate WiFi network that's low security (no access to internet, just IoT devices) once I start deploying ESP8266 based devices. Yes, people can easily get the credentials but you'll be connected to a mostly useless network.

Security is very situational. What kind of attackers are you protecting against? How valuable is what you are protecting? It's hard to give advice without knowing more about that.